# "No internet connection" message appears while using sign in by Apple

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, swift5

I recently implemented "Sign In with Apple" feature in my iOS application, I tested it on many devices including an iPad and iPhone on Wi-Fi and cellular network on `iOS 13.5.1` and it worked correctly but when I submitted the app to App Store the reviewer told me that the feature is not working and he sent a screenshot

[image]

I was only able to reproduce the same error by manually disable Wi-Fi from the control center after taping "Sign In with Apple" button. I told the reviewer that it maybe just a temporary connection loss but he assured me that he tested it on an iPhone and iPad and he was connected to Wi-Fi.

Any ideas why this error might happen?

```swift
  func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
    return self.view.window!
  }

  func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    switch authorization.credential {
    case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:

      // Create an account in your system.
      let userIdentifier = appleIDCredential.user
      let givenName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName
      let email = appleIDCredential.email

      // Call my server
      break

    case let passwordCredential as ASPasswordCredential:
      let email = passwordCredential.user
      let password = passwordCredential.password

      // Call my server
      break

    default:
      break
    }
  }

  func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
  }
```

> By the way this alert is not being displayed by my application it's
> being displayed by iOS it self.

Comment: iOS 30.5.1 does not exist - can you ensure you've accurately reflected all details in your post?

Comment: Sorry it is iOS 13.5.1 @esqew

Comment: Show us your implementation of `authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error`

Comment: @KirilS. Thank you for your reply. I updated the question. My `didCompleteWithError` callback is empty.

Comment: Don't believe the reviewer. Apple always tests with no internet connection. Your app needs to behave well under those circumstances. "I was only able to reproduce the same error by manually disable Wi-Fi from the control center after taping "Sign In with Apple" button" Yes, so you need to write your code in such a way that if that happens, your app is well-behaved. You need to intervene in such a way that that Could Not Connect dialog doesn't appear.

Comment: @matt Showing such an alert is a good behavior if the reviewer is really testing without an internet connection, Because signing in requires an internet connection so i cannot change anything in my app's behavior. Also as i mentioned earlier, this alert is being displayed by iOS not by my App.

Comment: Okay, fine.  I'm just trying to help you solve that problem. I'm on your side. It's the reviewer you have to win over. The reviewer is telling you that you can't get into the App Store if that alert appears. You're saying you want the alert to appear. Stalemate.

Comment: @matt I'm sorry if my comment came as aggressive, I didn't meant it to be I was just trying to clarify the issue. Thank you for trying to help. Peace :)

Comment: @matt By the way it's clear from the screenshot (which was sent by the reviewer) that their device was connected (Wi-Fi icon in the status bar), So i'm suspecting some kind of bug in Apple's sign in feature, Have you encountered a similar issue before?

Comment: Sure, and so can you. On your device, go into the Developer settings (in the Settings app) and turn on the Network Link Conditioner. You can set up your device to simulate total loss of signal. That's what the reviewer is doing. The network is there, but the Internet is missing in action. This is why I say don't believe the reviewer. Sure, there's _hardware_ connectivity. The reviewer told the truth (because you asked the wrong question). But the _network_ is down.

Comment: @matt Wow, Indeed that is what's happening, I tried to set the `Network Link Conditioner` to "100% loss" and to "Very Slow Connection" and in both cases i got the same alert, But i don't know how to fix such a problem, The reviewer is literally crippling the connection and expecting the feature to work properly. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I already made my suggestion and you rejected it.